# Is there a difference between `this.function()` and `function.call(this)`?

Tags: javascript

After reading [this tutorial](https://ui.dev/this-keyword-call-apply-bind-javascript/) I think I have some grasp of how to use call and apply. However, I'm still left slightly confused.

**Is there any situation in which using `function.call(this, arguments)` would be different than using `this.function(arguments)`**?

If not, then why do we need the `call` function?

Comment: You have basically illustrated the difference: if `function` exists as a property of `this`, it’s the same. If `function` is a variable, then `this.function` isn’t possible in the first place.

Comment: @deceze if you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const person = {
  name: "Bob",
  greet: function() { console.log("Hello " + this.name) }
};

const thank = function() {
  console.log("Thanks " + this.name);
}
```

`person.greet()` is the same as `person.greet.call(person)`, but the first is more succinct, so this is why this variant exists.

[`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) function is useful when function is not member of the object. You can't call `person.thank()`, you must call `thank.call(person)`.

Comment: **As a side note:** You can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) object to a function, which may cause some quite "surprising" [results](https://jsfiddle.net/TeWu/Lyoea8gk/12/) . JS is powerful, but that doesn't mean that you should abuse that power ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference (other than that using `.call` means that your code may take an unexpected path if someone overwrite the property `call` of the function or `Function.prototype.call`). However, you can write `this.function()` only when the function actually exists as a property of `this`!

Consider this example that shows how it can make sense to use `call`:

```js
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('div')

// console.log(nodes.map(node => node.innerText)) would fail
// because nodes is of type NodeList which doesn't have a map
// method. But, it is array-like (has numeric indices and a length
// property) so we can use the original map method of the array
// prototype:

console.log(Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, node => node.innerText))
```

Or another example:

```js
// This simulates an object we got from somewhere else
const something = {
  val: 123,
  calc (x) {
    return this.val / x
  }
}

// We want to monkey-patch the calc method so it doesn't return Infinity
// on x being zero (this may be necessary if we don't have access to the
// library that provided the something object, and forking it is not
// feasible)
const prevCalc = something.calc
something.calc = function (x) {
  if (x === 0) {
    return null
 } else {
    // Without using call, the invokation of the original method would
    // not have the right this
    return prevCalc.call(this, x)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.function(arguments)` is same as `this.function.call(this, arguments)`. So when we should use call?

Question: suppose we have two objects Cycle and Mechanic

```
function Cycle(pressure) {
  this.pressure = pressure;
  this.decreasePressure = function() {
    this.pressure -= 1
  }
}

function Mechanic(mechanicWorking) {
   this.mechanicWorking = mechanicWorking
}
```

Suppose if mechanic wants to decrease Cycle's pressure then how he should do it.
ans:

```
Cycle cycle = new Cycle(24);
Mechanic mechanic = new Mechanic(true);
mechanic.decreasePressure = cycle.decreasePressure;
mechanic.decreasePressure() // will give error
but:
mechanic.decreasePressure.call(cycle) // will decrease pressure of cycle
```